# PL/SQL no data found exception with cursors

Tags: oracle, loops, exception, plsql, cursor

I'm writing a procedure that opens 2 cursors, and needs to do some logic for each one, but do nothing if `no_data_found`.
If I'm not handling it, the fetch inserts null values, if I throw an exception, it ignores the second part.

code:

```
create or replace procedure pro_name(param1,param2....)
as
    var1
    var2
    TYPE cur_typ IS REF CURSOR;
    c cur_typ;
    etc...
begin
sql_str := 'select from ' || param1 || 'where some_cond..';

open c for sql_str;
loop

fetch c into v1, v2 , v3; 
DO STUFF...

end loop;
commit;


-- go all over again with different table

sql_str2 := 'select from ' || param2 || 'where some_cond..';

open c2 for sql_str2;
loop

fetch c into v1a, v2a , v3a; 
DO STUFF...

end loop;
commit;

end;
```

Where should I place the error handling ?

Comment: Why would either of these return a `no_data_found` exception?  It is not an error to fetch from a cursor that returns no rows.  My guess is that you are thinking of what happens when you code a `SELECT ... INTO` that has to return exactly 1 row.

Comment: i don't know.
I open the cursor, and when using v1, v2, and v3 - they all have null values, since sql_str return no rows.
how can i skip executing the first `DO STUFF` ?...

Comment: Are you saying that the query returns no rows?  Or that it returns rows where all three columns are `NULL`?  If the query returns no rows, you'd simply put your `EXIT` before the `DO STUFF`.

Comment: `exit when c%notfound;`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff, is that the syntax ? exit when c%notfound ? to exit just the loop ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to exit your loop when no row was found by the fetch (see [Working with Cursors](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2013/13-mar/o23plsql-1906474.html)):

```
FETCH c INTO v1, v2, v3; 
EXIT WHEN c%NOTFOUND;
```